# Remove the white space below image

Tags: css, image, border, whitespace, removing-whitespace

In Chrome the image on the right hand side of my banner has a small white space under it. The odd thing is - when using developer tools as soon as I make a change to ANY css property, the image seems to realign itself and the white space disappears.

I have added properties to the image such as:
display:block;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
vertical-align: text-bottom;

[This is my page.](http://blog.ekarda.com/)

How it looks in chrome:
[image]

How it looks in other browsers:
[image]

How can I get rid of this space?

Comment: This might address the issue of white space under your image:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common issue, I noticed myself in my own HTML web development when using CHrome and Developer Tools. Theres seems to be a glitch in the HTML render when you have the developer tools open. It happens every so often, but I know it is a weird bug. I never notice it in any other browser.

My suggestion to you, is to just ignore it for now :)

(if it doesn't break your HTML of course)

Seems like it is just a minor UI space.

Good Luck

-Kiru

Comment: Thanks for that - It still leaves the issue of why the white space is there though, and how to remove it. The white space is there without developer tools being open.